# what happens when we type cast from lower datatype to higher datatype

Tags: c, casting

Will the accessibility of memory space get changed or just informing the compiler take the variable of mentioned type?

Example:

```
int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 123456789;
    printf("ans is %d\n",(int)a);
}
```

Output:

```
overflow in implicit constant conversion a= 123456789.
ans is 21.
```

Here I know why it's causing overflow. But I want to know how memory is accessed when an overflow occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of simple: Since `char` typically only holds one byte, only a single byte of `123456789` will be copied to `a`. Exactly how depends on if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` (it's implementation-specific which one it is). For the exact details see e.g. [this integer conversion reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions).

What *typically* happens (I haven't seen any compiler do any different) is that the last byte of the value is copied, unmodified, into `a`.

For `123456789`, if you view the hexadecimal representation of the value it will be `0x75bcd15`. Here you can easily see that the last byte is `0x15` which is `21` in decimal.

What happens with the casting to `int` when you print the value is actually nothing that wouldn't happen anyway... When using variable-argument functions like `printf` values of a smaller type than `int` will be [***promoted***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`. Your `printf` call is *exactly* equal to

```
printf("ans is %d\n",a);
```

Comment: The behaviour is implementation-defined (may or may not behave as described in your first paragraph)

Comment: @M.M -- implementation-defined if `char` is signed, well-defined if unsigned